# Using Zbar.jar for Bar code scan, but it is not working in Android 6.0 and up

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am getting error while opening scanning bar code on the below line of code:

```
 static
{
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}
```

After that getting run time exception as mentioned below:

```
02-19 00:35:54.101 17727-17727/com.trialliancebarcode E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.trialliancebarcode, PID: 17727
                                                                        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.trialliancebarcode-1/lib/arm/libiconv.so: has text relocations
                                                                            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
                                                                            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                            at com.trialliancebarcode.BarcodeScanner.<clinit>(BarcodeScanner.java:48)
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not using **ZBAR** but i work on project Reading **barcode** 
i use **mobile vision Api** supported by google try it 
[**Check this Link**](https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. Download the latest ZBar project [here](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)
2. grab the latest .so from barcodescanner/zbar/src/main/jniLibs, and replace the relative .so in your project.
3. Run your app.

(Works well targetSdkVersion 25, buildToolsVersion '25.0.3', compileSdkVersion 25, **or below**)